# Vector Calculus: Can a matrix be extracted from a closed integral?

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I have a vector field $\vec{F}$, which at every point in space is multiplied by some values given by a matrix A: i.e., $\left[A\right]\vec{F}$. I then want to compute a closed loop integral around some points in this space on a curve $C$:

$$
\oint_C \left(\left[A\right]\vec{F} \right)\cdot d\vec{C}
$$

If the matrix A is position-invariant, am I able to remove it from the integral? i.e.:

$$
\oint_C \left(\left[A\right]\vec{F} \right)\cdot d\vec{C} \stackrel{?}{~=~} \left[A\right] \oint_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{C}
$$

Comment: Yes but not like that.  You want to fully contract the rank-2 tensor $A$ with the rank-2 tensor $\int_C\vec{F}(\vec{x})\otimes\mathrm{d}\vec{x}$: $\int_CA\vec{F}(\vec{x})\cdot\mathrm{d}\vec{x}=A_{ji}\int_C F_i\,\mathrm{d}x_j$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral on the left evaluates to a number, while the right hand side is a matrix times a number, so they aren't even the same type of thing.

Comment: So the answer is no -- thanks for pointing that out!